# Will servlet filter for cache control can create out of memory issue?

Tags: javascript, java, memory-management, servlet-filters, cache-control

I have written no cache filter for cacheable ssl page login.do. My question here is will this code lead to out of memory issue ? because when i deployed the application with this change the server was no getting started and when i disabled my change it got started.
Is this file changes creating issue or there can be different issue?

Web.xml

```
<filter>
<description>Adding session to log files</description>
<filter-name>SessionUserFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.sanju.filter.SessionUserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>  
 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>SessionUserFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/app/login.do</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>
```

SessionUserFilter class

```
public class SessionUserFilter implements Filter {
        private FilterConfig filterConfig;
    
        @Override
        public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {
            this.filterConfig=filterConfig;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            this.filterConfig = null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, FilterChain Chain) throws IOException,ServletException{

            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
    
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;//setting response header value 
            httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");//setting no cache in response header 

            httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security" , "max-age=7776000; includeSubdomains");
    
            Chain.doFilter(request,response);
    
            }
    //setters and getter
        public void setFilterConfig(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {
            this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
        }
    
        public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
            return filterConfig;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally  it should not but you can check the memory when you deploy your application.